# Is it possible to connect an app to a bluetooth device without pairing or knowing anything about the device until it's searching?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'd like to have a line of devices I'm using to connect to any phone without having the phone ask to pair. I'd just want it to "pair" via the app itself while the device is searching and my app will take care of the rest. Is it possible for my app to do this?

Comment: Try bluetooth low energy.

Comment: @QianSijianho that worked! it seems like my own implementation of the broadcast receiver didnt work but BluetoothLeScanner.startScan(callback) worked when i changed the device's mode to low energy. I'm still not sure what i did wrong though

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Just pass Bluetooth device address to this service class it will connect and runs in the background.

```
  public class BluetoothServices extends Service {
    enter code here

private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
public static final String B_DEVICE = "MY DEVICE";
public static final String B_UUID = "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
// 00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;
public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;
public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2;
public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;

private ConnectBtThread mConnectThread;
private static ConnectedBtThread mConnectedThread;

private static Handler mHandler = null;
public static int mState = STATE_NONE;
public static String deviceName;
public static BluetoothDevice sDevice = null;
public Vector<Byte> packData = new Vector<>(2048);

//IBinder mIBinder = new LocalBinder();


@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    //mHandler = getApplication().getHandler();
    return mBinder;
}
public void toast(String mess){
    Toast.makeText(this,mess,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    BluetoothServices getService() {
        // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
        return BluetoothServices.this;
    }
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    String deviceg = intent.getStringExtra("bluetooth_device");


    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

            connectToDevice(deviceg);

    return START_STICKY;
}
private synchronized void connectToDevice(String macAddress){
    BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(macAddress);
    if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING){
        if (mConnectThread != null){
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
    }
    if (mConnectedThread != null){
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }
    mConnectThread = new ConnectBtThread(device);
    toast("connecting");
    mConnectThread.start();
    setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
}
private void setState(int state){
    mState = state;
    if (mHandler != null){
       // mHandler.obtainMessage();
    }
}
public synchronized void stop(){
    setState(STATE_NONE);
    if (mConnectThread != null){
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }
    if (mConnectedThread != null){
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }
    if (mBluetoothAdapter != null){
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }

    stopSelf();
}

public void sendData(String message){
    if (mConnectedThread!= null){
        mConnectedThread.write(message.getBytes());
        toast("sent data");
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(BluetoothServices.this,"Failed to send data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean stopService(Intent name) {
    setState(STATE_NONE);

    if (mConnectThread != null){
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }

    if (mConnectedThread != null){
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    return super.stopService(name);
}

/*private synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket mmSocket){

    if (mConnectThread != null){
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }
    if (mConnectedThread != null){
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedBtThread(mmSocket);
    mConnectedThread.start();


    setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
}*/

private class ConnectBtThread extends Thread{
    private final BluetoothSocket mSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mDevice;

    public ConnectBtThread(BluetoothDevice device){
        mDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;
        try {
            socket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString(B_UUID));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mSocket = socket;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {
            mSocket.connect();
            Log.d("service","connect thread run method (connected)");
            SharedPreferences pre = getSharedPreferences("BT_NAME",0);
            pre.edit().putString("bluetooth_connected",mDevice.getName()).apply();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            try {
                mSocket.close();
                Log.d("service","connect thread run method ( close function)");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //connected(mSocket);
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedBtThread(mSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();
    }

    public void cancel(){

        try {
            mSocket.close();
            Log.d("service","connect thread cancel method");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private class ConnectedBtThread extends Thread{
    private final BluetoothSocket cSocket;
    private final InputStream inS;
    private final OutputStream outS;

    private byte[] buffer;

    public ConnectedBtThread(BluetoothSocket socket){
        cSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        inS = tmpIn;
        outS = tmpOut;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        buffer = new byte[1024];
        int mByte;
        try {
            mByte= inS.read(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("service","connected thread run method");

    }


    public void write(byte[] buff){
        try {
            outS.write(buff);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void cancel(){
        try {
            cSocket.close();
            Log.d("service","connected thread cancel method");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    this.stop();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: I revised my question. Does this still apply?

Comment: yes just pass Bluetooth mac Address of available devices from the list

Comment: By using the BroadcastReceiver and registering it?